# Deployed tabs not visible in production

Tags: lightning, deployment, tab, visibility

I deployed some tabs from sandbox to production but they are not visible.

I checked profile settings. I see my tabs listed under Tab Settings > Custom Tab Settings. For all three profiles I have they are all set to "Default On".

Within Lightning App Builder, I go to Select Items. I see my tabs appear under "Selected Items".

What other settings do I need to check to make them visible?

Comment: Are those Tabs available in the app that you are trying to view?

Comment: Yes they are. I can see them in the Custom Tabs page under Settings > Tabs.

Comment: That page will show you the tabs you have created. But for a tab to be visible, it needs to be added in an app (say Sales, or a custom app) along with the profile permissions. You may like to verify if the tab you are expecting is available for the app that you are viewing or not.

Comment: Inside Lightning App Builder, I go to Select Items. Under "Selected Items" I see my custom tabs there. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, so are you still not able to view those tabs in the app?

Comment: Still unable to, unfortunately.

Comment: Check if this link helps -- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000176786&type=1. Verify if the object is still not in development.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81029/discussion-between-ohseekay-and-jayant-das).

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to user Jayant Das, I have managed to solve my problem. Apparently this is a known issue - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001CsgQAE&title=custom-tab-not-visible-in-lightning-experience.

In my case, my tabs are not part of a managed package, so I deleted the tabs and remade them again. I made sure on step 3 of the process to check the "Append tab to users' existing personal customizations" option.